# convert any non DAG into DAG (Directed acyclic graphs)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science, directed-graphs

It is always possible to convert any non DAG into a DAG, by changing its order, if not limiting the number of changes. Is this true?

Is there a proof?

**[Newly Updated/Edited for exact definitions]**

Non DAG is a directed graph with directed cycles.

Since a directed graph $G=(E,V)$ is a graph associated with ordered pairs. By changing its order, I mean for any directed edge $e_{i\to j} \in V$, one may change it to $e_{j\to i}$. That is, given a directed graph $G=(E,V)$ which is not a DAG, if there always exists a DAG $G'=(E,V')$ for which
$$e_{i\to j} \in V' \,\textrm{ if and only if }\, e_{i\to j} \textrm{ or } e_{j\to i}\in V.$$

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "non DAG". As in, which part is the "non" applied to? And what do you mean by "changing its order"? For example, suppose you have a single directed loop...

Comment: @prets I rephrased my problem in more detailed description.

Comment: There is something unclear to me. The input to your problem is a directed graph $G$, and the desired output is a DAG. Is it allowed for the input graph to have both the edges $e_{v\to w}$ and $e_{w\to v}$ for some vertices $v$ and $w$? Some authors allow this, others do not, and it affects whether or not it is possible for the output to be a simple graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always* turn $G=(V, E)$ into a DAG. To do this, number the vertices of $G$ from $1$ to $|V|$, and redirect each edge so that it points from a lower numbered vertex to a higher numbered vertex.

---

*The only way this could fail is there existed two vertices $v,w$ in $G$ such that both of the edges $v\to w$ and $w\to v$ are present in $G$. Applying my procedure, the resulted graph would have a doubled edge, so would not be simple. Different authors disagree as to whether a $G$ with two such opposing edges counts as a simple directed graph.

Comment: Note that this may produce a non-simple directed graph (take e.g. a 2-cycle). Which may or may not be a problem, depending on how we feel about non-simple graphs.

Comment: Apologize to @prets and Mike. I am not working on graph theory thus when I talk about graph, I basically think of simple graph for all the time. Thus I should have corrected it as a simple DAG (without selfloops and multiedges). In this case, is it still possible to produce a non-simple directed graph from a simple DAG? BTW, what is 2-cycle? Thanks.

Comment: By 2-cycle I mean two vertices, call them 1 and 2, with one edge $1 \to 2$ and one edge $2 \to 1$. Whether you consider this a multi edge is up to you, I suppose, but they're not the same *directed* edge, so I would not.

Comment: @Silentmovie Does the edit make things clear?